# FirebaseRecyclerOptions query for certain array of keys

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB1tL.jpg)
I should extract only certain keys from drinkCategories and display them in FirebaseRecyclerOptions. I'm wondering how should I manipulate the query or FirebaseDatabase reference to only look for specific keys.

Edit: below is my code, arrayOfCategories inside equalTo is not real array, just a representation of what I want to acomplish. "equalTo" takes one string but is there another way to query only certain keys, example i want to query only by keys category-id-7 and category-id-9 (these two keys are stored inside arrayOfCategories), ignore all other keys.

```
    categoriesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("drinksCategories");
    Query query = categoriesRef.orderByKey().equalTo(arrayOfCategories);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>()
            .setQuery(query, Category.class)
            .build();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Category model) {
            String categoryId = getRef(position).getKey();
            categoriesRef.child(categoryId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.hasChild("image")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), snapshot.getValue(Category.class).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String description = snapshot.child("description").getValue().toString();
                        String profileImage = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                        String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();


                        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(profileImage, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
                        Drawable drawable;
                        if (id == 0) {
                            id = getResources().getIdentifier("no_image", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
                            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
                        }
                        else
                            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
                        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(drawable).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);


                        holder.txtMenuName.setText(name);
                        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                                recyclerMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                insertDrinks(name);
                                recyclerMenuDrinks.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        String name = snapshot.child("name").getKey().toString();
                        String description = snapshot.child("description").getKey().toString();

                        holder.txtMenuName.setText(name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);
            return new MenuViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    recyclerMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
```

Comment: Are you asking how to order and filter data in Firebase Realtime Database. Because that's covered in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data and it's much more likely that we can help if you can show what you tried based on that, and based on other questions about the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+query

Comment: Are you asking how to the Realtime Database based on two values?

Comment: 2 or more. With further research, I don't think the requested is possible that way, I would need to customize the database to match my needs.